# While scanf with boolean operator

Tags: c++

I saw this piece of code today:

```
while(scanf("%d %d",&x,&y),x||y)
{
    ....
```

From what I've understand, it enters the loop if some of the values (x or y) is true.

Since the [scanf docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) says:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

I have rewritten the code to:

```
while(scanf("%d %d",&x,&y) >= 1)
{
   ....
```

But on an [online programming challenge site](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/) the first while works, the second fails.

Am I right on my assumptions ? What are the differences between this two pieces of code?

(I am tagging as C++, because I have tested in C++ 4.8.2 - GNU C++ Compiler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of arguments it matches, but the first code fragment throws out that result and just checks to see if either `x` or `y` is true. The second fragment returns that you matched at least one integer, regardless of value.

Consider the input `"0 0"`. In the first case, `scanf()` returns 2, but `x || y` returns `false`. In the second case, your conditional is `true`.

Comment: That was exactly the case. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

The first code gives `while` the result of `x||y`, this is correct

However, the second code compares the return value of `scanf` and `1`, and then gives `while` the comparing result.

run this code and you'll be clear.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cout<<(scanf("%d %d", &x, &y), x||y)<<endl;
    cout<<(scanf("%d %d", &x, &y))<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```